# MacBook Pro Error Xampp doesn't work after Big Sur update Version 11.3

Tags: php, macos, xampp

Error Xampp doesn't work after Big Sur update Version 11.3

Today I updated my mac to macOS Big Sur Version 11.3 and I can't open XAMPP. When I click on Start it give me Error starting "XAMPP" stack with this details cannot calculate MAC address: hv_vm_create unknown error -85377023.

I have all my Projects in htdocs, and I can't reach it if I don't press Mount.

Do you know how solve this problem?

Comment: https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=80760&sid=37cbb8d2b2850b65f4cb9e413f747906

No solution in the xammp forum as well now.

Answer (score 0):

Same here. You won't have a solution until Xampp is update to support the mac's new security config. If you do not have a backup. I suggest you convert your vm using a docker image and later unzip into this one.
The Xampp VM terminal also won't open now

Comment: I agree with Yogeswar, Docker is the best option and one to avoid installing a lot of stuff in the machine.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

Download the new version for hyperkit, copy your "machine"-folder from your backup to the "stackman"-folder. Run XAMPP.

https://community.bitnami.com/t/bitnami-wordpress-mac-os-11-3-big-sur-error-starting-wordpress-stack/94776/9